# Gatling user injection for 50 total users in 1 hour adding 10 users per 5 minutes

Tags: testing, gatling

I need to setup a Gatling Test with a total of 50 concurrent users, but I have a problem because there is no choice to get it.

I use **rampUsers(10) over (60 minutes)** but it gets only 10 concurrent users.
Using **constantUsersPerSec(users) during (60 minutes)** is too stressful.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done as follow:

```
val scn = scenario("Test").during(1 hours) {
  exec(http("test").get("/"))
}
setUp(scn.inject(splitUsers(50) into atOnceUsers(10) separatedBy(5 minutes))
  .protocols(httpConf))
```

see http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.3/general/simulation_setup.html:

> splitUsers(nbUsers) into(injectionStep) separatedBy(duration): Repeatedly execute the defined injection step separated by a pause of the given duration until reaching nbUsers, the total number of users to inject.